# How to include Python Pillow as Homebrew formula requisite?

Tags: python, ruby, python-imaging-library, homebrew, recipe

I used to use Homebrew tap formulas to distribute my self maintained programs. However, it is imposible for me to do with some programs which use Pillow, because Homebrew fails when try to install it isolate.

Example of a recipe which uses Pillow:

```rb
class Monoshape < Formula
    include Language::Python::Virtualenv

    desc "Extracts monochromatic shapes"
    homepage "https://github.com/GlezSeoane/monoshape"
    url "https://github.com/GlezSeoane/monoshape/archive/v1.0.tar.gz"
    sha256 "6edbecfc60db6f91fba6e520769f811009743eec89d655c54e4e6006ad5b0dbb"

    depends_on "python"

    resource "filetype" do
        url "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/53/298887541ae479f8467d4d23e028c6d15f9811da25c582297fd3869666b7/filetype-1.0.5.tar.gz"
        sha256 "17a3b885f19034da29640b083d767e0f13c2dcb5dcc267945c8b6e5a5a9013c7"
    end

    resource "Pillow" do
        url "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/fe/18125dc680720e4c3086dd3f5f95d80057c41ab98326877fc7d3ff6d0ee5/Pillow-6.1.0.tar.gz"
        sha256 "0804f77cb1e9b6dbd37601cee11283bba39a8d44b9ddb053400c58e0c0d7d9de"
    end

    def install
        virtualenv_install_with_resources
        man1.install "manpages/monoshape.1"
    end

    test do
        system "python", "-c", "'import monoshape.__main__'"
    end
end
```

Homebrew error output when try to use the formula:

```sh
brew reinstall --verbose --debug ./Formula/monoshape.rb
```

```
...
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/1a/6b2971adc1bca55b9a53ed1efa372acff7e8b9913982a396f3fa046efaf8/Pillow-6.0.0.tar.gz
/usr/bin/curl -q --show-error --user-agent Homebrew/2.1.7\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 10.14.5\)\ curl/7.54.0 --location --silent --head --request GET https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/1a/6b2971adc1bca55b9a53ed1efa372acff7e8b9913982a396f3fa046efaf8/Pillow-6.0.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/glezseoane/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/ea7321a9356188da36d495f4135bfd7dfeb7add8558b773a6421e9096db03779--Pillow-6.0.0.tar.gz
==> Verifying ea7321a9356188da36d495f4135bfd7dfeb7add8558b773a6421e9096db03779--Pillow-6.0.0.tar.gz checksum
tar xof /Users/glezseoane/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/ea7321a9356188da36d495f4135bfd7dfeb7add8558b773a6421e9096db03779--Pillow-6.0.0.tar.gz -C /private/tmp/d20190708-31029-1m7e24t
cp -pR /private/tmp/d20190708-31029-1m7e24t/Pillow-6.0.0/. /private/tmp/monoshape--Pillow-20190708-31029-1w8theb/Pillow-6.0.0
chmod -Rf +w /private/tmp/d20190708-31029-1m7e24t
==> /usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/bin/pip install -v --no-deps --no-binary :all: --ignore-installed /private/tmp/monoshape--Pillow-20190708-31029-1w8theb/Pillow-6.0.0
Created temporary directory: /private/tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-aihec4je
Created temporary directory: /private/tmp/pip-req-tracker-6pqza4qj
Created requirements tracker '/private/tmp/pip-req-tracker-6pqza4qj'
Created temporary directory: /private/tmp/pip-install-tjb4rpw6
Processing /private/tmp/monoshape--Pillow-20190708-31029-1w8theb/Pillow-6.0.0
  Created temporary directory: /private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0
  Added file:///private/tmp/monoshape--Pillow-20190708-31029-1w8theb/Pillow-6.0.0 to build tracker '/private/tmp/pip-req-tracker-6pqza4qj'
    Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0/setup.py) egg_info for package from file:///private/tmp/monoshape--Pillow-20190708-31029-1w8theb/Pillow-6.0.0
    Running command python setup.py egg_info
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'azure-pipelines.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.azure-pipelines'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Source in /private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0 has version 6.0.0, which satisfies requirement Pillow==6.0.0 from file:///private/tmp/monoshape--Pillow-20190708-31029-1w8theb/Pillow-6.0.0
  Removed Pillow==6.0.0 from file:///private/tmp/monoshape--Pillow-20190708-31029-1w8theb/Pillow-6.0.0 from build tracker '/private/tmp/pip-req-tracker-6pqza4qj'
Skipping bdist_wheel for Pillow, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: Pillow
  Created temporary directory: /private/tmp/pip-record-1a95g79y
  Running setup.py install for Pillow: started
    Running command /usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-1a95g79y/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/bin/../include/site/python3.7/Pillow
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'azure-pipelines.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.azure-pipelines'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
    writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    building 'PIL._imaging' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
    building 'PIL._imagingcms' extension
    building 'PIL._imagingft' extension
    building 'PIL._webp' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DHAVE_WEBPMUX -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.10.0/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.3.1/include/openjpeg-2.3 -I/private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0/src/libImaging -I/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/_webp.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/_webp.o
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.10.0/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.3.1/include/openjpeg-2.3 -I/private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0/src/libImaging -I/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/_imagingft.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/_imagingft.o
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.10.0/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.3.1/include/openjpeg-2.3 -I/private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0/src/libImaging -I/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/_imagingcms.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/_imagingcms.o
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/libImaging
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_OPENJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DPILLOW_VERSION="6.0.0" -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.10.0/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.3.1/include/openjpeg-2.3 -I/private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0/src/libImaging -I/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/_imaging.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/_imaging.o
    src/_imagingft.c:25:10: fatal error: 'ft2build.h' file not found
    #include <ft2build.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    building 'PIL._imagingtk' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/Tk
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -Isrc/Tk -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.10.0/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.3.1/include/openjpeg-2.3 -I/private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0/src/libImaging -I/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/_imagingtk.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/_imagingtk.o
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/_webp.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lwebp -lwebpmux -lwebpdemux -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL/_webp.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -Isrc/Tk -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.10.0/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.3.1/include/openjpeg-2.3 -I/private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0/src/libImaging -I/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/Tk/tkImaging.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/Tk/tkImaging.o
    building 'PIL._imagingmath' extension
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.10.0/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.3.1/include/openjpeg-2.3 -I/private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0/src/libImaging -I/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/_imagingmath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/_imagingmath.o
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/_imagingcms.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -llcms2 -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL/_imagingcms.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    building 'PIL._imagingmorph' extension
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.10.0/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.3.1/include/openjpeg-2.3 -I/private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0/src/libImaging -I/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/_imagingmorph.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/_imagingmorph.o
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/_imagingtk.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/Tk/tkImaging.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL/_imagingtk.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/_imagingmorph.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL/_imagingmorph.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/_imagingmath.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/PIL/_imagingmath.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_OPENJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DPILLOW_VERSION="6.0.0" -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.10.0/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.3.1/include/openjpeg-2.3 -I/private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0/src/libImaging -I/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/decode.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/decode.o
    In file included from src/decode.c:869:
    /private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0/src/libImaging/Jpeg2K.h:11:10: fatal error: 'openjpeg.h' file not found
    #include <openjpeg.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
  Running setup.py install for Pillow: finished with status 'error'
Cleaning up...
  Removing source in /private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0
Removed build tracker '/private/tmp/pip-req-tracker-6pqza4qj'
ERROR: Command "/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-1a95g79y/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/bin/../include/site/python3.7/Pillow" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0/
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 178, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 414, in run
    use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 58, in install_given_reqs
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 951, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 776, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "/usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-1a95g79y/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/bin/../include/site/python3.7/Pillow" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-req-build-rgrd0jy0/
/usr/bin/curl --version
/usr/libexec/java_home --xml --failfast
/usr/libexec/java_home --xml --failfast
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/debrew.rb:13:in `raise'
BuildError: Failed executing: /usr/local/Cellar/monoshape/1.0/libexec/bin/pip install -v --no-deps --no-binary :all: --ignore-installed /private/tmp/monoshape--Pillow-20190708-31029-1w8theb/Pillow-6.0.0
```

**Since macOS Mojave 10.14.5 with Python 3.7 and Homebrew updated**.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to include additional `depends_on` clauses to help Pillow locate compiled libraries: e.g., `depends_on "openjpeg"` (which provides `openjpeg.h`).